# How do file paths work in a Dynamic Web Application in Java and Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, path

I am building a Dynamic web application in Eclipse.

In my `Login.java` servlet, I want the `doGet()` method to perform some logic (i.e. check if the user is already logged in) and open the page `login.jsp` located in the `webapp` folder, as seen in the image.

I've tried variations of

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/src/main/webapp/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

but I keep getting 404 errors that `The requested resource is not available.`.

How do I determine the proper path that the system wants in order to display this page?

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: `src/main/...` are Maven conventions for building your project. They do not exist at deployment/runtime.

Comment: simply try `request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(request, response);`

Comment: @user3218114 Thanks, surprisingly, it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If the path begins with a `/` it is interpreted as relative to the current context root (it means jsp is directly placed under `webapp` or `webContent` folder in the project)

  For example:

  ```
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
  ```
- If the path does NOT start with forward slash,it is considered relative to the original request.

[Read more...](http://www.coderanch.com/t/361247/Servlets/java/ServletRequest-RequestDispatcher)